# How can I optimize this code to generate larger strings faster?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, c++17

I am making a program in C++ that is supposed to generate a string based on 2 inputs.
The first input is the amount of letters that can be used from the English alphabet to generate it (if the input number is N, it will use the letters starting from A to the Nth letter of the alphabet to generate the string).
The second input determines the character length of the string.

**Generating requirement**:

When adding a new char to the end of the string the program needs to check that there are no duplicate neighboring substrings being created (example of duplicate neighboring substrings: **AA**, AB**AA**, **ABAB**, ABAC**AA**, ABAC**ABAB**, **ABACABAC**,...)

**Program example:**

N (string length) = 10 
C (letters used from the alphabet) = 5

1. suitable string - A
2. suitable string - AB
3. suitable string - ABA
4. suitable string - ABAC
5. suitable string - ABACA
6. suitable string - ABACAB
7. suitable string - ABACABA
8. suitable string - ABACABAD
9. suitable string - ABACABADA
10. suitable string - ABACABADAB

**Solution:** ABACABADAB

**Problem:** 
The program works well when generating smaller strings, but when generating larger strings e.g. 5000 chars long, it takes a while to generate them. I would like to optimize the code so that it would reduce the time it takes to generate large strings as much as possible. This is where I have been struggling to find a solution on how to do so. 
Are there any ways I could optimize the code so that it would reduce the time it takes to generate larger strings?

**My code:**

```
char alphabet[26] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

std::string generateUniqueStringIterative(int lettersUsed, int depth) {
   std::string tempStr, uniqueString;
   bool foundDuplicate = false;
   char changeChar = ' ';
   for (int deep = 0; deep < depth; deep++) 
   {
       // Loop through all letters
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lettersUsed; i++)
       {
           if (alphabet[i] == changeChar) {
               i++;
           }
           // Create temp string
           tempStr = uniqueString + alphabet[i];
           // Loop through the string to check for neighboring duplicate
           for (unsigned int j = 1; j < (tempStr.size() / 2) + 1; j++)
           {
               foundDuplicate = false;
               // If duplicate found set foundDuplicate var to true and break out of loop
               if (tempStr.substr(tempStr.size() - j, j) == tempStr.substr(tempStr.size() - (j * 2), j)) {
                   foundDuplicate = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (!foundDuplicate || deep == 0)
           {
               // Update uniqueString and break from loop
               uniqueString = tempStr;
               changeChar = ' ';
               break;
           }
       }
       if (foundDuplicate && deep != 0) {
           // If all chars return duplicates, iterate back and change the last char 
           changeChar = uniqueString.back();
           uniqueString.pop_back();
           deep--;
       }
   }
   // Return final unique string
   return uniqueString;
}
```

Comment: The `alphabet` lookup table is not needed. `alphabet[i]` can be replaced with `'A' + i`

Comment: @prapin -- that is not required to work, and with, for example, EBCDIC, which has gaps between the alphabetic characters, it won't work. The only requirement that C and C++ impose on character sets is that the **digits** must be contiguous and increasing, so `'0' + i` always works.

Comment: You should avoid unnecessary memory dynamic allocations, if you already know the final length of the string, use `reserve()`. I cannot restrain myself to add this: writing `i++` when you can write `++i` is a sign of sloppyness